# Implementing Receiver in SPARK

Tags: scala, apache-spark, packet-capture, spark-streaming

I have been trying to implement receiver for SPARK 0.9 . I have captured packets using Jnetpcap library and need to pass it to spark in Scala. Is it enough to write the capturing part of the packet in "def receive()" method?

**Edit:** Here is code from [this link](https://github.com/swe0523/PacketCapture-in-Spark/blob/master/src/main/scala/PacketCapture1.scala) that captures packets using the Jnetpcap library:

```
import java.util.Date
import java.lang.StringBuilder
import org.jnetpcap.Pcap
import org.jnetpcap.packet.PcapPacket
import org.jnetpcap.packet.PcapPacketHandler

object PacketCapture1 {
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val snaplen = 64 * 1024 // Capture all packets, no trucation
    val flags = Pcap.MODE_PROMISCUOUS // capture all packets
    val timeout = 10 * 1000
    //val errbuf = new StringBuilder()

    val jsb = new java.lang.StringBuilder()
    val errbuf = new StringBuilder(jsb);
    val pcap = Pcap.openLive("eth0", snaplen, flags, timeout, errbuf)
    if (pcap == null) {
      println("Error : " + errbuf.toString())
    }
    println(pcap)
    val jpacketHandler = new PcapPacketHandler[String]() {

      def nextPacket(packet: PcapPacket, user: String) {
        println("Received packet at %s caplen=%4d len=%4d %s\n", new Date(packet.getCaptureHeader.timestampInMillis()),
          packet.getCaptureHeader.caplen(), packet.getCaptureHeader.wirelen(), user)
      }
    }
    pcap.loop(30, jpacketHandler, "jNetPcap works!")
    pcap.close()

  }
}
```

How to implement spark receiver for the packets captured using this code?

Comment: I suggest you include relevant code examples and provide a clearer description of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Here is a link to the scala code that captures packets using Jnetpcap library: https://github.com/swe0523/PacketCapture-in-Spark/blob/master/src/main/scala/PacketCapture1.scala      How to implement spark receiver for the packets captured using this code?

Answer (score 5):

You have to create a custom NetworkReceiver (or Receiver in Spark 1.0+) and implement the `onStart()` method. For Spark 0.9, see http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.1/streaming-custom-receivers.html

For spark 1.0 (strongly recommended), see http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-custom-receivers.html